# How to fix syntax error for AngularJS component attribute?

Tags: angularjs, angular-components

Hi I am using this component as a datetimepicker:
https://dalelotts.github.io/angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker/

I have multiple date fields generated at runtime, and this component need to refer to the field name as it is shown in code below

```
<datetimepicker 
    ng-model="param.DefaultValues[0]" 
    datetimepicker-config="{ dropdownSelector: '#{{param.Name}}' }" />
```

But I am getting the error from angular.js **after selecting a date**:

[image]

**I am only asking about this syntax, how to fix it?**

Full piece of code is this:

[image]

**UPDATE**

Sorry guys, you all suggested the same syntax,

```
datetimepicker-config="{ dropdownSelector: '#' + {{ param.Name }} }"
```

but it didnt work, breaks right away when I open the page:

> Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '{' invalid key at column
>   28 of the expression [{ dropdownSelector: '#' + {{ param.Name }} }]
>   starting at [{ param.Name }} }].

I think closing single quote is missing here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double curly bracket `{{ }}` interpolation works with the `id` attribute because the [$compile service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) is doing interpolation binding to a native HTML attribute. The `datetimepicker-config` attribute is an AngularJS component attribute which is evaluated as an [Angular Expression](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression).

Don't use interpolation `{{ }}` inside Angular expressions.

```
<!-- DONT interpolate in Angular Expressions 
<datetimepicker 
    ng-model="param.DefaultValues[0]" 
    datetimepicker-config="{ dropdownSelector: '#{{param.Name}}' }" />
-->

<!-- INSTEAD -->
<datetimepicker 
    ng-model="param.DefaultValues[0]" 
    datetimepicker-config="{ dropdownSelector: '#' + param.Name }" />
```

---

*inside what angular expressions? double curly brackets {{}} IS the angular expression. the a value for datetimepicker-config attribute has nothing to do with angular, its simply a JS object {}*

The `datetimepicker-config` attribute is evaluated with one-way `<` binding. It is **not evaluated as a simple JavaScript object**. It is evaluated an [Angular Expression](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression). Double curly brackets are [*DOM interpolation binding.*](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interpolate) Double curley brackets `{{ }}` are not legal syntax inside Angular Expressions.

For more information, see:

- [AngularJS Developer Guide - **AngularJS Expressions vs. JavaScript Expressions**](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression#angularjs-expressions-vs-javascript-expressions)
- [AngularJS $parse Service API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$parse)
- [AngularJS $interpolation Service API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interpolate)

> > [Syntax Error: Token '{' invalid key at column 28 of the expression `{ dropdownSelector: '#' + {{ param.Name }} }` starting at `{ param.Name }} }`](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$parse/syntax?p0=%7B&p1=invalid%20key&p2=28&p3=%7B%20dropdownSelector:%20%27%23%27%20%2B%20%7B%7B%20param.Name%20%7D%7D%20%7D&p4=%7B%20param.Name%20%7D%7D%20%7D&)
>
> #### Error: $parse:syntax
>
> #### Syntax Error
>
> #### Description
>
> Occurs when there is a syntax error in an expression. These errors are thrown while compiling the expression. The error message contains a more precise description of the error, including the location (column) in the expression where the error occurred.
>
> To resolve, learn more about [AngularJS expressions](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression), identify the error and fix the expression's syntax.
>
> [— AngularJS Error Reference - $parse:syntax](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$parse/syntax?p0=%7B&p1=invalid%20key&p2=28&p3=%7B%20dropdownSelector:%20%27%23%27%20%2B%20%7B%7B%20param.Name%20%7D%7D%20%7D&p4=%7B%20param.Name%20%7D%7D%20%7D&)

Comment: georgeawg, inside what angular expressions? double curly brackets {{}} IS the angular expression. the a value for datetimepicker-config attribute has nothing to do with angular, its simply a JS object {}

Comment: Are you saying that you tried the solution and it didn't work?

Comment: georgeawg, it worked ! :) its weird, but it works !! thanks man! I understand now, I will bookmark your answer for future reference. Thanks!

Comment: I haven't read attentively that Dom interpolation part, my mistake of course

Answer (score 1):

Like the documentation says, `dropdownSelector` expects a string. So you would have to concatenate:

```
<datetimepicker 
    ng-model="param.DefaultValues[0]" 
    datetimepicker-config="{ dropdownSelector: '#' + param.Name }" />
```

Comment: My mistake. Shouldn't have used the Angular brackets there.

Answer (score 0):

Fix to

```
<datetimepicker 
data-ng-model="data.embeddedDate" 
datetimepicker-config="{ dropdownSelector: '#' + {{ param.Name }} }" />
```

add **data-ng-model="data.embeddedDate"** to your ng-model

Comment: added data- according to this doc https://dalelotts.github.io/angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker/, exactly as it say, but its unrelated, the problem with angular expression inside that js object inside attribute syntax ))

Comment: Maybe it's a conflit with angular version , test with another version of angular and see how it goes